# How can i update with modelformset_factory on Django

Tags: python-3.x, django

I used the modelformset_factory method for multiple photo uploads. But when I want to update the post, I don't know how to do this, I tried something, but this only serves to re-upload photos and upload the uploaded photos again. How can I update or delete a previously uploaded photo? Also, I cannot access the photos in formset as {{formset.image}}. How can I access this?

Views.py

```
def post_update(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=slug)
    if not request.user.is_authenticated and not request.user == post.seller or not request.user.is_admin:
        raise Http404
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(PostImage, form=PostImageForm, extra=5, can_delete = True)
    form = PostForm(data=request.POST or None, instance = post, files = request.FILES or None)
    
    formset = ImageFormSet(data=request.POST or None, files= request.FILES or None, queryset=PostImage.objects.filter(post__slug=slug))
    if form.is_valid():
        if formset.is_valid():
            for forms in formset.cleaned_data:
                if forms:
                    image = forms['image']
                    print(forms['image'])
                    photo = PostImage(post=post, image=image)
                    photo.save()
        form.save(commit=True)
        messages.success(request,"Success")
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('gayrimenkul:detail',kwargs={'slug':form.instance.slug}))
    return render(request,'post_update.html',{'form':form,'formset':formset,'slug':slug})
```

post_update.html

```
{% extends "main_page.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block icerik %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<div class="row">
<div class="container">

    <h2 class="page_header">İlan Ver</h2>
    <hr>
    {% if form.errors %}
        {{form.errors}}
    {% endif %}
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.media}}
            {{form|crispy}}
            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
            {{formset}}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <button type="submit" id="inp" class="btn btn-outline-primary" style="float:right;">Kaydet</button>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
 {% endblock %}
```

Creating posts works successfully.

```
def post_create(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        raise Http404
    ImageFormSet = modelformset_factory(PostImage, form=PostImageForm, extra=5)
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        formset = ImageFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, queryset=PostImage.objects.none())
        if post_form.is_valid():
            created_post = post_form.save(commit=False)
            created_post.seller = request.user
            created_post.save()
            for form in formset.cleaned_data:
                if form:
                    image = form['image']
                    photo = PostImage(post=created_post, image=image)
                    photo.save()
            messages.success(request,'Success')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('gayrimenkul:detail',kwargs={'slug':created_post.get_slug()}))
    else:
        post_form = PostForm()
        formset = ImageFormSet(queryset = PostImage.objects.none())
    return render(request,'post_create.html',{'form':post_form,'formset':formset})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before checking if the form is valid just filter the model of the formset

```
     data = PostImage.objects.filter(post=post)
```

Give index of the item for a formset item starting form 0 and (f)the item itself and if the item of the id is not changed than save previous item itself else change the database image with the new image you have updated.

```
            if formset.is_valid():
                for index, f in enumerate(formset):
                    if f.cleaned_data:
                        if f.cleaned_data['id'] is None:
                            pic = PostImage(post=post, image=f.cleaned_data.get('image')) 
                            pic.save()

                    elif f.cleaned.data['image'] is False:
                       pic = PostImage.objects.get(id = request.POST.get('form-' + str(index) + '-id'))
                       pic.delete()
                        
                        else:
                            pic = PostImage(post=post, image=f.cleaned_data.get('image'))
        
                            d = PostImage.objects.get(id=data[index].id) #get slide id which was uploaded
                            d.image = pic.image # changing the database title with new title
                         
                            d.save()
```

This might work for you or get you some idea.

Comment: Thank you. It's work :) but still i cant delete the uploaded photos :)

Comment: i have edited my post where i have added elif statement for deleting the image. Hope this may be of some help. Here, i am deleting the fields by getting the name of the input tag. You can inspect the fields and see for yourself.

Comment: i found it. ```elif f.cleaned.data['image'] is False:``` should be ```elif request.POST.get('form-'+str(index)+'-DELETE') != None:```